# When is the right time to logout the user using JWT, the time when access token expires or the time when the refresh token expires?

Tags: jwt, angular7

1. I am using JWT for authenticating users. I can see two types of tokens (access token to make requests to the back-end and refresh token) generated by JWT. So, my question is when the right is time to logout the user? The time when the access token expires or the time when the refresh token expires?
2. What is the better way to get the new access token using the refresh token endpoint according to the user's active or inactive state?

Answer (score 0):

the refresh token exists so that your service can keep using the credentials of the user on their behalf even after the access token expires. so if you have a refresh token, there is no need to "logout the user" when their access token expires

> A Refresh Token contains the information required to obtain a new Access Token or ID Token.
>
> Typically, a user needs a new Access Token when gaining access to a resource for the first time, or after the previous Access Token granted to them expires.

https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-token/current

If you let the access token expire and do not use the refresh token to generate a new access token, the user will have to log in again if you would like to perform some action on their behalf (access a resources using their access token). The user is "logged out" when their refresh token expires. The user does not need to be active for you to use their refresh token